# indentation-based outliner? (for windows XP)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm looking for an SDI ("Single Document Interface", i.e. without document tabs), plain text editor that supports outlines based on how many Tab characters are added at the beginning of each line (can fold indented segments of text)?
No need for a separate tree view, I want to see the entire document in one pane instead.

Notepad++ can do it when switched to YAML language, but it has tabs.

Also I would like a clearer visual representation of the folded segments of text than a simple horizontal line (as it is done on Notepad++). The perfect solution would be something similar to how folded code segments look like in MS Visual Studio or SharpDevelop or MonoDevelop, except I want it to fold indented text instead of whatever is considereed to be a "code block" in a programming language

I'd also like it to be binary-portable (runnable on any PC from a USB stick without installation, like PortableApps.com programs, but not necessarily packaged by PortableApps.com).

Comment: @Mikhail I have rejected your edit. If you do not have reputation to comment, [earn that first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting), instead of changing someone else's question.

Comment: It turns out that *Mikhail* = *outliner*

Comment: XP should already be dead

Answer (score 1):

If Notepad++ supports all your requirements except for a non-tabbed interface, you're in luck! There are 2 ways to disable tabs in the Notepad++ interface:

#### Disabling tabs in Notepad++

1. Create an empty file named `asNotepad.xml` in the same directory as `notepad++.exe`.

OR

2. Go Preferences -> Settings. On the `MISC.` tab, untick "Enable" under Document Switcher. On the `General` tab, tick "Hide" under Tab Bar.

Notepad++ also has a portable mode that you've specified as your requirement.